# Require function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, require

I tried this on visual editor. also I have node.js on my system. When I try this:

```js
const http = require('http');
```

Help me to fix the … dots under the require before debugging it.

It appears when I try to type `require`. and then a tooltip shows to fix it by ES6.

but it couldn't fix it.

Comment: This is not a node.js issue. Your code is 100% correct. This is an issue of your code editor not knowing node.js

Comment: can you tell which code editor you are using and can you publish the whole code?

Comment: @iftikharyk The entire code is not required to find a solution to this question.